# How to apply Tracker.autorun? Meteor.userId() undefined right after refreshing page

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-react, meteor-tracker

I have a restricted page using Meteor.userId() and roles:

```
class AdminPage extends Component {
render() {
 return (
  <div>
    {
      Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), 'admin') ? (
        <Master_Layout renderCenter={<Article_Editor />}/>
      ) : browserHistory.push('/')
    }
  </div>
)
}
}
```

This code redirects user to "/" after refresh because Meteor.userId() is undefined. How do I make sure Meteor.userId() is not undefined before rendering the page after refresh?

I searched for answers. I found Tracker.autorun as a solution, but I did not understand how to apply it.

Thank you for help. I updated the code:

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = { user: '' };
}
componentDidMount() {
var $this = this;

Tracker.autorun(function () {
  let user = Meteor.user();
  if(user != undefined) {
    $this.setState({ user: user });
  }
});
}
render() {
if(Roles.userIsInRole(this.state.user, 'admin')) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Master_Layout renderCenter={<Article_Editor />} />
    </div>
  )
} else {
  return <div>loading...</div>
}
}
}
```

Observed needed parts: 

$this = this;

user = Meteor.user(); //Meteor.userId() does not work.

removed browserHistory because it will navigate away before user is defined.


Now I just need to find a solution on defining user/userId before render mounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Tracker.autorun` allows you a function to be called automatically whenever it's dependent reactive data source changes.

Simply speaking, `Tracker.autorun()`  takes a function as input, runs this function now and returns whenever the data source changes later on.

In your case, you can use `Tracker.autorun()` for tracking the user document, since `Meteor.user()` and `Meteor.userId()` are reactive. In `componentDidMount()` call `Tracker.autorun()` and save the user document in elsewhere when it changes.

Hope following code snippet helps:

```
componentDidMount() {
        var context = this;

        Tracker.autorun(function(){
            let user = Meteor.user();
            if (user != undefined) {
                context.setState({ user: user, });
            }
        });
    }
```