# Is it a bad idea to set current user as session variable in meteor / react framework?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, meteor-react

I am using meteor + react to develop a small app, mostly to understand the workings of react. I am currently not using any form of Flux or Redux.

During multiple instance in the app I have to check if the person using the app is logged in. I am currently doing this with a dataContainer from react-meteor-data.

```
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
...
class NavigationBar extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                this.props.currentUser
            </div>
        )
    }
}
... 
export default createContainer(() => {
    let currentUser = Meteor.user()
    return {
        currentUser,
    };
}, NavigationBar);
```

While this works fine, I am starting to find it a bit annoying to have to wrap every component in which I want to check the current user. Since I have customized login and logout functions anyway I was wondering if there is anything wrong (insecure) about setting the current user in a session variable on loggin like this:

```
> Session.set('currentUser',Meteor.userId());
```

and then just setting it to null on logout?

Thx alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's alright to store user's info in `session variable` or pass them to the `child component` as `props`. But make sure you are removing the session variable properly when the user is logging out. In your case:

```
Session.set('currentUser',null);
```

Comment: Cool, thx for the reply. Do you happen to know whats considered "best practice" for a case like this?

Comment: I usually use Tracker.autorun() for this purpose. Once I explained it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42252800/1067326

Comment: I see, is there a benefit of doing it via context instead of session variable (which as far as I know is reactive as well)? I guess your approach via the Tracker.autorun() is more stable in a sense that you don't have to explicitly change the session variable on login/logout.

Answer (score 1):

I would say instead of keeping the user information in the session, you can keep a bool value as true, so if the currentUser is not null, you can set it to true and then you can easily use this boolean variable to manage UI rendering on the front-end, now I don't know what are your project requirements but this seems to me a good way of handling the condition whether a user is logged in or not. I would appreciate any corrections to my answers.

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the response, although that does not quite address my concerns (mostly security/safety). My project is pretty much a list of items created by different people. One is only allowed to edit an item if he is the creator (i.e. currentUserId == creatorId). So a boolean prolly won't quite cut it. Although I like the idea for general assessment whether or not a user is logged in and then showing logout instead of login button.

Comment: Aah got it, so in that case you can use this boolean value for general assessment but if you have security concerns then instead of storing the currentUserID, you can create a getter method in your backend that when called returns the currentUserID and then you can have a check like getCurrenUserID == creatorID, then do whatever you want to do.

Comment: One more thing is, you can save the userID in your cookie but have a strict check on you code that there isn't any weak part through which the hacker could perform attacks like sql injection...

Answer (score 1):

Saving the current user ID is quite secure. But make sure that it's updated correctly. Like you don't have the prev user id if user will logout.

Comment: So you are saying its alright to put it in a session variable?

Comment: Yes, If it is some not secure data. There is no much difference from any others session vars.
Except of course you are willing to save the whole user doc. Then i wouldn't recommend it.  

But it really handful to have some user data available all the time. Like subscribed chat rooms or something like this. Something not secure. Having the credit card data saved global means that local software / scripts and just people can stole it.